# Valgrind does debug error

Tags: 12.04, software-installation, programming, c

I have been trying to follow the online tutorial for 
[Learn C The Hard Way](http://c.learncodethehardway.org/book/learn-c-the-hard-waych5.html).

However after setting up valgrind (I followed other links that help setting up valgrind on ubuntu 12.04), when I try to debug the c executable, I find the following errors.

```
ayusman@ayusman-ubuntu:~/lcthw$ valgrind ./ex4
==1984== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==1984== Copyright (C) 2002-2011, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==1984== Using Valgrind-3.7.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==1984== Command: ./ex4
==1984== 

valgrind:  Fatal error at startup: a function redirection
valgrind:  which is mandatory for this platform-tool combination
valgrind:  cannot be set up.  Details of the redirection are:
valgrind:  
valgrind:  A must-be-redirected function
valgrind:  whose name matches the pattern:      strlen
valgrind:  in an object with soname matching:   ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
valgrind:  was not found whilst processing
valgrind:  symbols from the object with soname: ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
valgrind:  
valgrind:  Possible fixes: (1, short term): install glibc's debuginfo
valgrind:  package on this machine.  (2, longer term): ask the packagers
valgrind:  for your Linux distribution to please in future ship a non-
valgrind:  stripped ld.so (or whatever the dynamic linker .so is called)
valgrind:  that exports the above-named function using the standard
valgrind:  calling conventions for this platform.  The package you need
valgrind:  to install for fix (1) is called
valgrind:  
valgrind:    On Debian, Ubuntu:                 libc6-dbg
valgrind:    On SuSE, openSuSE, Fedora, RHEL:   glibc-debuginfo
valgrind:  
valgrind:  Cannot continue -- exiting now.  Sorry.

ayusman@ayusman-ubuntu:~/lcthw$
```

Is there something that I can do to make valgrind finally work?

I have ubuntu 12.04 on virtual box.
My laptop is a Windows 7 64 bit OS.

Comment: valgrind worked fine for me out of the box, but i can't say what libraries i already had installed.  valgrind is available from repo.  you don't need to compile is like learn C the hard way states.  installing from repo will handle the dependency issue for you

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Ok,
I did intsall libc6-dbg like so

```
sudo apt-get install libc6-dbg
```

and valgrind seems to work fine.

Thanks to the ubuntu forum link:

http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1017692

Comment: @Goaler444 I just did. Thanks for reminding.

Comment: as the other answer points, doing `sudo apt-get install libc6-dbg:i386` could be a solution depending on the binary to be _valgrinded_ (64 bits vs 32 bits).

Answer (score 42):

I got essentially the same message (except that `ld-linux-x86-64.so.2` was replaced by `ld-linux.so.2`).  I had installed Valgrind using `apt-get` so libc6-dbg was already included as a dependency.

I haven't fully resolved this yet, but a clue is that the error correlates with my use of `-m32` when building.

So it would seem that, in my case, the problem is the lack of a 32-bit version of libc6-dbg (or some of its components), when building on a 64-bit install of Ubuntu 12.04.

---

### Solution (for my case)

For me, the following command made things work...

```
sudo apt-get install libc6-dbg:i386
```

This is discussed at https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/eglibc/+bug/881236

Note: The package `libc6-dbg:i386` doesn't show up as an available option in Synaptic or via command-completion of `apt-get` -- but it was there anyway.

Comment: There's a good change you'll need help building first: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7412698/86967

Comment: this should be marked as correct; the `:i386` is the key here.

Comment: It was the 32-bit that did the trick!

Comment: This solved it for me.. I was seeing this error on a vagrant machine. As the other commenters said, this should be marked as correct. (libgc-dbg was already installed as a valgrind dependency, it was the i386 that did the trick)

Comment: This answer correctly dealt with 32bit binaries. `libc6-dbg` was already hinted in `valgrind`'s error message.

Comment: I have `libc6-dbg:i386` installed and Valgrind still doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I struggled with this for a very long time, compiling in -m32 mode worked, but it was a pain in the ass, moreover if I wanted to use e.g. -lcrypto, I couldnt compile in -m32 since I didnt have openssl in 32bit installed.

So I read through a lot of similar posts, usually advising installing libc6-dbg:i386 ... I think this solved the problem for -m32, but it wasnt what I was looking for. So after a long time a came to this: https://lists.ubuntu.com/archives/foundations-bugs/2013-November/173202.html

So try running dpkg -l libc6* and if you see libc6-amd64, this could help you. But read it carefully esp. point 2, cause you wont be able to use any commands after you remove the libc6-amd64 package, so prepare a liveCD and follow the instructions :) It helped me solve the problem, but it took me about 3 hours and couple of fear moments. I recommend to backup your data before you do that, because if you fail, there will be probably no way back.

And be carefull at point 4! You cant simply write the command suggested there
`ln -s /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.17.so /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2`
because it would make a symbolic link in the live cd `/` folder.
Also you have to have root rights to write to lib64.
So how I did it was: (i had / folder on my broken valgrind disk opened through the liveCD terminal)

1)`sudo rm ./lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 //removing old link`

2)`sudo ln -s /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.17.so ./lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2`

//you refer to the file on the disk with broken linux, but if you wrote just / instead of ./ you would create the link in the liveCD / folder

Hope I didnt forget anything and this will be helpful.

P.S: I wonder if it is possible to change the symlink before you remove the libc6-amd64 package (you would bypass the whole liveCD stuff) but Im not sure.

Comment: Please watch your language !!!